# Multiple route values to the controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a got a problem while passing parameters to the controller
Here is my view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Models.Distributer>
 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new{id=item.DistributerID,user=item.Name }) 
}
```

My Controller

```
   public ActionResult Edit(int? id,string name)
    {
        ViewBag.name = name;
 }
```

In the Edit view just to display the name.

My RouteMap

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Route1",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{user}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Distributers", action = "Edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional,user="" }
        );
```

Here I find that variable name in the controller is null.Inorder to test the route works.I pull the link from the loop,ie;

```
    @model WebApplication2.Models.Distributer
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",new{id=item.DistributerID,user=Model.Name})
```

This works Fine..string name=value(not null)

Why is it so??

Comment: Best guess - your URL is not matching the route you are expecting it to match (because the first match, not the best match, always wins). But without seeing your entire route configuration or the URL you are calling to get that result, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: the above custom route map is before the default route map as you got this idea from earlier threads..It is exactly matching my route

Comment: Yes, your custom route is before your default route. But are there other routes before this one? Without seeing them all (including any attribute routes, WebApi routes, etc) this question is too ambiguous to answer. Please show all of your routes and explain what URL you are attempting to access the application with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in your route and in your call to `Html.ActionLink` is `user`, but on your action method signature, it's `name`. In other words, `user` is being passed, but your action method does nothing with it. Conversely, the `name` parameter is never provided. Make sure that the parameter name lines up everywhere and you're golden.

Comment: From what I gather, the OP's question is "why is the `name` parameter NOT null?". Your assumption seems to imply the opposite.